# Bootstrap - dynamically add input feedback glyphicon

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having trouble getting over the hump on this (most likely) obvious problem. I am validating inputs using onblur.

If the input fails for whatever reason I am using this to give the user feedback on the input:

```
$('#' + $element.id).closest('.form-group')
.addClass('has-error has-feedback')
.append('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></span>');
```

**Working:**

- Getting red input border
- Getting red label

**Not working:**

- Glyphicon is not picking up the parent class rules therefore not
  getting positioned/colored

correctly.

Since I am dynamically creating the html element and appending it to the parent, the system isn't seeing the inheritance. Timing seems to be the trouble perhaps? Not sure the best solution other than adding some sort of callback to the addClass method?

The markup I am generating matches the documentation on bootstrap. Just no joy.

```
<div class="form-group has-error has-feedback">
    <label for="lastName" class="control-label">* Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" class="form-control required">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: apend first, then add classes

Comment: Maybe insert the icon from begining with `display: none;` and then show it.

Comment: Your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/8kxdf/. What version of Bootstrap CSS are you using? you need at least v3.1.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your response! I was working on a fiddle and /u/kolala_dev beat me to it.

I am using the [SASS version of bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) I must have had an older version - now I am getting the correct colors etc. Need to update my positioning and I'm golden. 

Thank you again for your time!